# Borel cohomology for circle actions on odd spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose we have a $S^1$-action on the odd sphere $S^3$ as follows:
$$ \lambda \cdot (z_1, z_2) = (\lambda \cdot z_1, \lambda^2 . z_2)$$

I would like to understand the (Borel) equivariant cohomology of $S^3$ under these kind of actions. Spectral sequences are not giving me enough information (or maybe I can't use them well enough lol). How can I proceed with these calculations?

In general for any odd integer $n = 2k-1$ we can choose integers $m_1, ..., m_k$, and define the circle action on the odd sphere $S^n \subset \mathbb{C}^k$ :
$$ \lambda \cdot (z_1,\cdots, z_k) = (\lambda ^{m_1} \cdot z_1, \cdots, \lambda ^{m_k} \cdot z_k) $$
How would I compute the borel cohomologies $H^*_{S^1}(S^n; \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Did you look at the spectral sequence with $E_2^{i,j}=H^i(BS^1;H^j(S^n))$? It has only two non-zero rows, the nontrivial groups $E_2^{2p,0}$ and $E_2^{2p,n}$ being infinite cyclic. The computation all comes down to knowing the differential $E_2^{0,n}\to E_2^{n+1,0}$, which takes generator to $m_1\dots m_k$ times generator.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie thanks for your response. I was (am) stuck at figuring out what these differential operators look like. Would you please expand on why they are multiplication by $m_1m_2...m_k$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb C^k$ yields a rank $k$ complex vector bundle $V=ES^1\times_{S^1}\mathbb C^k$ on $BS^1$. You are interested in the cohomology of $S(V)=ES^1\times_{S^1}S^{2k-1}$, the total space of the unit sphere bundle of the vector bundle $V$. The Serre spectral sequence of the sphere bundle has only two nontrivial rows, so it boils down to a long exact sequence, the Gysin sequence
$$
\dots \to H^{p-2k}(BS^1)\to H^{p}(BS^1)\to H^p(S(V))\to \dots
$$
The map to $H^p(BS^1)$ (i.e. the only nontrivial differential in the spectral sequence) is given by multiplication by the Euler class of the vector bundle, an element of $H^{2k}(BS^1)$. Let's write the cohomology ring $H^\ast(BS^1)$ as $\mathbb Z[u]$ where $u\in H^2(BS^1)$ is the Euler class of the universal complex line bundle. So we need to know the integer $d$ such that the Euler class of $V$ is $du^k$.

The action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb C^k$ is the direct sum of $k$ actions on $\mathbb C$, so $V$ is the direct sum of $k$ complex vector bundles of rank $1$ (line bundles). The Euler class of a direct sum of bundles is the product of the Euler classes, so the problem of determining the differential is reduced to the case when $k$ is $1$. In that case if the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb C$ is by $\lambda \mapsto \lambda^m$ then the class is $mu\in H^2(BS^1)$; the line bundle associated to the action is the $m$th tensor power of the universal line bundle, and Euler class gives an isomorphism from the group of isomorphism classes of complex line bundles on a space $B$ to $H^2(B)$.

Therefore the Euler class of $V$ is $m_1\dots m_ku^k$. So the number $d$ is $m_1\dots m_k$, and if the numbers $m_j$ are all different from zero then the cohomology ring $H^\ast(X)$ is the quotient of $H^\ast(BS^1)=\mathbb Z[u]$ by the ideal generated by $du^k$.